# Multiple nested with not working: I just get the first one

Tags: eloquent, with-statement, laravel-5.7

I execute an eloquent query using multiple `with`.
This is the query I execute:

```php
$offers = \App\Offer::
    with(['event_date.event.place.location'], ['event_date.event.theatre.prices'])
    ->whereHas('event_date', function ($query) use ($location_id) {
        $query->where('events_dates.date', \Carbon\Carbon::today()->format('Y-m-d'));
        if (!empty($location_id)) {
            $query->whereHas('event', function ($query) use ($location_id) {
                $query->whereHas('place', function ($query) use ($location_id) {
                    $query->where('places.location_id', $location_id);
                });
            });
        }
    })
    ->skip($skip)
    ->take($take)
    ->get();
```

The problem is that I only get the first with clause (`event_date.event.place.location`), and not the second one.

I think the problem is that both `with` clause have the same root (`event_date.event`), but I do not know howto solve it.

**UPDATED**

This is the json I get:

```php
{
   "data":[
      {
         "id":12,
         ...
         "event_date":{
            "id":1119,
            "event_id":6,
            "date":"2018-10-28 00:00:00",
            ...
            "event":{
               "id":6,
               "title":"Evento di test ennesimo",
               ...
               "place":{
                  "id":2,
                  ...
                  "location":{
                     "id":2320,
                     "name":"Roma",
                     "code":null,
                     "root_id":29,
                     "lft":11910,
                     "rgt":11911,
                     "level":3
                  }
               },
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

As you can see there are record info of `event_date.event.place.location`, but not of `event_date.event.theatre.prices`.

Comment: Please explain "I only get the first with clause". What does "get" mean?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass multiple arrays to `with()`. Either a single array or multiple strings:

```php
with('event_date.event.place.location', 'event_date.event.theatre.prices')
with(['event_date.event.place.location', 'event_date.event.theatre.prices'])
```